# Android: Making padding dynamic in a FrameLayout

Tags: android, dynamic, padding

I'm following an example where the author hard coded a paddingTop to 370px.

...

How do I make that paddingTop dynamic? When I run this in 2 AVDs with HVGA and WVGA80 I get the frame floating at different heights. I'd like to say something like paddingTop=80%, but that doesn't work...

Thanks!
llappall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HVGA and WVGA80 I get the frame floating at different heights

The best overall solution is probably to convert the app to use DIPs (Device Independent Pixels) throughtout. It may be as simple as replacing 'px' with 'dip' in your measurements.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html